# Huffman compression/decompression

Tags: c++, compression

I am using C++ to code the Huffman compression/ decompression algorithm on the CPU.When I time my code, given that I have built the huffman tree, my code is taking 24s to decompress 1 million floating point numbers. My hardware is below:

Laptop w/ Intel core i5, 6 GB ram, 64 bit os,5.5 windows experience index,2.3GHz clock speed.

Can some with some experience in compression let me know if the  above value is correct or is my code too slow?

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code?  Do you have a reason to believe it's inefficient?

Comment: When I implemented Huffman compression many years ago, the decompression seemed quite fast. You probably need to review your code.

Comment: I would just compare it to other implementations on the net like this one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9021/Simple-and-fast-Huffman-coding

Comment: You say that you build the huffman tree, which leads me to suspect you forgot to use tables. Decoding bit-by-bit with the tree is a disaster. Use tables.

Comment: Can you eleborate on the table part. To be very specific, I am using the c++ map

Comment: @JonathanWood: Can you quantify "seemed quite fast"

Comment: @ThatBlairGuy: I have 5 years of programming experience.  Ppl here have > 15. Efficiency has a completely different meaning on SO

Comment: @Programmer I was referring primarily to this way http://www.compressconsult.com/huffman/#decoding but there are some variations that use different tables, such as the mythical "SHLD+BSR decoder". They all use tables though. Decoding bit-by-bit is not a serious strategy, it's only used to explain what you are doing conceptually.

Comment: `gunzip` on 1 million compressed random floats represented as strings takes `0.2` seconds on my machine so I'm sure your code could be faster. Whether or not your code is too slow is up to you and what you need your code for.

Comment: Are you testing release build performance? I have seen cases where debug builds run 100X slower than release builds.

Comment: Despite the vagueness of "too slow", the extreme numbers provided permit answering the question definitively as, yes, it's too slow.  So I would not move to close the question.

Comment: @Programmer: It's hard to quantify "seemed quite fast" as that was a long time ago running on a DOS system. But I can tell you that it was for a help system I wrote and bringing up a new topic, while maybe not instantaneous, did not create any type of annoying delay. It was near instantaneous for mostly smaller help topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is too slow.  Even if I assume 8-byte floats and a compression ratio of one, that is very conservatively almost a thousand cycles per decoded input bit.  Even bit-by-bit, traversing a binary tree should only take a few instructions per bit.  And there are much faster ways than bit-by-bit.